# jquery selector not working in IE 7 or Compatibility Mode

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery that works fine in IE 8:

```
var myVar = $(myField).parent().parent().find("a#hyp");
$(myVar).text("Notified!");
```

However, it does not work when I set my browser mode to IE7 or IE8 Compatibility Mode. I'm fairly certain that it is a problem with the selector ("a#hyp"), because I ran into a similar problem earlier where the click event of the anchor tag wasn't being picked up by jquery.

The anchor tag is a simple one:

```
<a id="hyp" href="#">Notify</a>
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you show the HTML too for completeness?

Comment: It shouldn't be causing this problem, but the `a` in the selector should be unnecessary since there should only be one element with a given ID.  It should probably even be quicker without the `a`.  Also, `myVar` is already a jquery object, so no need to re-wrap it in the 2nd line.

Comment: @kingjiv Using the `a` is important if this script runs on multiple pages and there are more than one element with that `id` attribute over different pages. Rare and not the best practice, but sometimes the case.

Comment: @kingjiv - thx for tip about double wrapping my jquery objects. I didn't realize that's what I was doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess that you might have more than one link with an `id="hyp"` and that's why you're using `$(myField).parent().parent().find("a#hyp");`.  You can't have more than one object with a given id in your page and you will get inconsistent results in different browsers if you do.  In any  case, since all ids must be unique, change your code to this (there's no need for any other qualification of the selector):

```
$("#hyp").text("Notified!");
```

Internally in jQuery, this will turn into a `document.getElementById("hyp")` which should work well in all browsers.

Comment: You are correct. There are multiple anchor tags on this page with the same ID. However, it is frustrating because I don't have much control over it. This particular code is .NET, and what I have is an anchor tag within an ItemTemplate of a GridView. When the GridView is rendered to the browser, it places an anchor tag with the same ID in each row. You have me thinking though that maybe I should use a .NET hyperlink instead, and then the ID will be different for each row. This might just fix my problem.

Comment: the problem was as you suggested: anchor tags with the same ID's. I fixed it by using asp.net hyperlinks, which then rendered anchor tags with distinct ID's. Of course, this forced me to change my jquery selectors a little, but in the end it worked out just fine.